# Data in database and google analytics does not match

Tags: database, analytics

Why are the counts I see in my database different than what I see in Google Analytics? The goal conversion number showing in Google Analytics is much lower than what I see in the database. This is the case for several months.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you tell is where you're putting the Google Analytics code, what the data is in the database etc?

Comment: The GA code is being implemented on a website that tracks information (i.e. every time a particular button is clicked). The data in the database is the number of people who click on a certain button on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Few reasons here

1. **Sampled data vs. unsampled data**: You can read about here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en - For API work i normally use a web query explorer to verify that my API call's are being sent and responses match to verify the data: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/
2. **Adblockers**: You might get hits/submissions from people where they are using an ad blocker, hence more entries in Database or Google Analytics.
3. **Users vs. Sessions vs. Hits**: You are looking at Unique Visitors/Sessions in Google Analytics instead of the total number of "Events", Not sure how your Goal is setup but best to use events and look at "Total Events" and "Unique Events" to get a sense.
4. **Implementation**: You may be firing JavaScript after the person has hit the button without waiting for the page change, can happen on some sites where you take them to a thank-you page or something. Best to check how this is setup and the order in which tag fires and page works.